# Python - Best way to spawn function in "detached" process

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, process, python-3.5

I have a function `f` that I want to spawn in a separate process that should have a lifetime independent of its parent. What is the best way to do this?

I have not found a way to use `multiprocessing.Process(target=f)` in a way that does not require joining the child at some point.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try prepending nohup to your script and use Popen...
Something like that:

```
import os, subprocess

subprocess.Popen(['nohup', 'script.py'], stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)
```

If you put the function in `script.py` it should work.